# SQL query where Mydate should be less than 2 years from the current date

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have one date column `MyDate` and I want those records in which `MyDate` should be less than current date by 2 years.

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: Your title and actual question are conflicting

Comment: removing my answer. it's not applicable to DB2. please be more specific next time you ask such a question

Comment: @user1782009 please see my new answer and if it solves your problem, please upvote it and accept it. cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DB2 you can use this

```
MYDATECOLUMN < CURRENT DATE - 2 YEAR
```

Answer (score 0):

if DB Server = MS SQL , then try :-

```
select *
from myTable
where MyDate < dateadd(year, -2, getdate())
```