# Fetch records with a where condition that specifies fetch records for this week in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, where-clause

I am using DB2. I want to know the number of applications (Records/row) since the last seven days including today and my date column is ReceivedDate.

I basically want to write a query that intents to do the following: (DB2), please help me.

```
Select count(*) from Applications WHERE ReceivedDate is within 7 days
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query where Mydate should be less than 2 years from the current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582599/sql-query-where-mydate-should-be-less-than-2-years-from-the-current-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch records from DB2 for the last 7 days (1 WEEK) from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101363/how-to-fetch-records-from-db2-for-the-last-7-days-1-week-from-today)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query, which uses `CURRENT DATE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Applications
WHERE ReceivedDate > CURRENT DATE - 7 DAY;
```

This answer assumes that a received date would never be in the future (since it can't have yet happened).

Comment: Tim, thank you how to test this? My data wouldn't give me rows by default as no proper data....However, I am gona run and ensure no syntax issues, in the meantime

Comment: Also Tim. how different is your answer to the one by FA06 above?

Comment: I can't help you test because a) you never showed us any sample data and b) I don't have DB2 running here locally.  Assuming the received date would never be in the future, our answers would be the same.

Comment: Tim thanks le tme verify and comment back. By the way your answer is readable and easy for me :)

Comment: No errors in code so am happy with your answer Tim, it says 5 mins wait time to accept

Comment: Tim, sorry I went for grabbing protein shake in kitchen and was thinking of you to mark it. Just back o desk and marked it :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
Select count(*) from Applications 
WHERE ReceivedDate>CURRENT DATE - 7 Days and ReceivedDate<=CURRENT DATE
```

Comment: Thank you, how different is your answer to Tim? For readability, I find his answer to be easy (For layman like me)

Comment: I gave you a vote for your answer, thank you so much